# Svchost.exe consuming so much memory

Tags: windows-server-2008, svchost

`svchost.exe` is consuming 1,3xx,xxx K memory in my Windows Server (2008) which possesses 10GB RAM.

I found the following services are contained in this process:

```
AppMgmt
BITS
CertPropSvc
gpsvc
IAS
IKEEXT
iphlpsvc
LanmanServer
MMCSS
ProfSvc
RasMan
RemoteAccess
Schedule
SENS
SessionEnv
ShellHWDetection
Themes
Winmgmt
wuauserv
```

What can I do to reduce the amount of memory consumed by svchost.exe?

Comment: What sort of workload do you have on this server?

Comment: I encountered something similar.  SENS is the common thread for me.